# Using Composer's autoloader with personal code

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, spl-autoload-register

I'm building a small project using Composer, but I now have to use some custom code, in the parent folder of vendor folder.

Similar file structure: *libraries* > *companyname* > *namespace* > *classfile.php*

Is it possible to effectively use the composer autoloader? It seems that it is, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around it.

Would it be easier to use a second autoloader script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We're loading in our own code via composer.

Our code is installed in the lib folder under our company name. Our composer file looks like this.

```
{
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "lib"
    },
    "require": {
        "twig/twig": "v1.15.1",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.5.4"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "CompanyName\\": "lib/companyName/src"
        }
    }
}
```

the autoload psr4 section is the important part. `CompanyName` will resolve files located in `lib/companyName/src`.

Inside lib/companyName/src, you'd have a file called `ThingDoer.php`

```
<?php

namespace CompanyName;

class ThingDoer {
    public static function doThings() {}
}
```

And now from anywhere in your codebase, you can call `CompanyName\ThingDoer::doThings();`

Comment: Correct (sort of, its CompanyName, capitalization matters i think), edited my answer for clarity.

Comment: Cool. This is great. Random, question for your case. Any particular reason you have the classes in a src folder? As opposed to just in the companyName folder?

Comment: Yep, our `companyName` folder contains `src`, `tests`, and `docs`. If we didn't have those other folders, we could just as easily dumped our code straight into `companyName`.